# Multiple PATCH requests REST End Point

Tags: angularjs, spring-data-rest

I have a Spring Data Rest project which expose a entities managed by JPA and hibernate.
I update several Many to Many relationship in the entity using several PATCH requests.

So I send PATCH requests to the end point, with list of entity urls the as the body for each many to many relationship.

The patch request happens concurrently so one request is proceeded and the second concurrent request gives

**Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)**

Is there way to PATCH the entity concurrently?
Example Entities are like,

```
User {

List<Role> roles;  

List<Module> modules;

}
```

concurrent patch requests are happening to both Role and Module.
**Edit** : this is the angular code that I use to patch.

```
   var patchRequests = [];
   angular.forEach(copy, function (value, property) {
                    if (angular.isArray(copy[property])) {
                        // If array contains more than zero elements
                        if (copy[property].length > 0) {
                            patchRequests.push(
                                $http.patch(url,copy[property].join('\n'), {
                                    headers: {
                                        'Content-type': 'text/uri-list'
                                    }
                                }));
                        }
                    }
                });
    $q.all(patchRequests);
```

the 'copy' object is like bellow

```
{"roles":["http://localhost:9002/api/roles/1","http://localhost:9002/api/roles/3"],"modules":["http://localhost:9002/api/modules/1"],"subModules":[],"userName":"hrandika","password":"password","email":"h@local","activated":true}
```

**Edit 2:**
Spring Data rest is just a interface

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long>{

}
```

Comment: Show us the code where you do the patching.

Comment: @RobertMoskal I have added the AngularJS code and the Object I use to patch. Simply i iterate over the object properties,select the arrays,if array length is > 0 then sent a PATCH.

Comment: It's the server side endpoint I think we need to see.

Comment: @RobertMoskal I have add the Edit 2. Its a interface annotated with '@Repository'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [HTTP Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2) spec:

> The server MUST apply the entire set of changes atomically and never
> provide (e.g., in response to a GET during this operation) a
> partially modified representation.  If the entire patch document
> cannot be successfully applied, then the server MUST NOT apply any of
> the changes.

all changes done by single patch requests have to be atomic. This is realized in Java through the utilization of a container or DB managed transaction.

Therefore, if two clients send in a patch to the server, either one of the clients has to wait till the first client finished his work or should fail.

As a patch can update any field (even of other resources), two separate patch requests may update the same field differently (similar to the optimistic lock examples used in DB race scenarios). In addition to that, a patch instruction should usually contain the steps necessary to transform state 1 to state 2. With [JSONPatch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) f.e. one request could remove a field from the collection while a further request tries to move the item to a further position. As both requests rely on the state they currently know, blindly applying those values can be dangerous.

HTTP Patch spec, though, also provides a hint on how to handle conflict scenarios for multiple patch requests:

> A PATCH request can be issued in such a way as to be idempotent,
> which also helps prevent bad outcomes from collisions between two
> PATCH requests on the same resource in a similar time frame.
> Collisions from multiple PATCH requests may be more dangerous than
> PUT collisions because some patch formats need to operate from a
> known base-point or else they will corrupt the resource.  Clients
> using this kind of patch application SHOULD use a conditional request
> such that the request will fail if the resource has been updated
> since the client last accessed the resource.  For example, the client
> can use a strong ETag [RFC2616] in an If-Match header on the PATCH
> request.

I therfore would advice to follow the spec and make use of ETag and If-Match HTTP headers to prevent collisions on multiple patch requests.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will look into it to in Spring data rest context and AngularJS,